# ‘setupClient’ is not a member of ‘gazebo’?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I followed the tutorial(animated box) here: [Animated box](http://www.gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=animated_box&cat=build_robot). After I 'make' it in the build folder, I got the error in the file *independent_listener.cc*

```
 error: ‘setupClient’ is not a member of ‘gazebo’
```

What's the matter?

PS. I use gazebo 1.9 with ROS hydro on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.
The content of independent_listener.cc:

```
#include <gazebo/transport/transport.hh>
#include <gazebo/msgs/msgs.hh>
#include <gazebo/gazebo.hh>

#include <iostream>

/////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Function is called every time a message is received.
void posesStampedCallback(ConstPosesStampedPtr &posesStamped)
{
  std::cout << posesStamped->DebugString();

  ::google::protobuf::int32 sec = posesStamped->time().sec();
  ::google::protobuf::int32 nsec = posesStamped->time().nsec();
  std::cout << "Read time: sec: " << sec << " nsec: " << nsec << std::endl;

  for (int i =0; i < posesStamped->pose_size(); ++i)
  {
    const ::gazebo::msgs::Pose &pose = posesStamped->pose(i);
    std::string name = pose.name();
    if (name == std::string("box"))
    {
      const ::gazebo::msgs::Vector3d &position = pose.position();

      double x = position.x();
      double y = position.y();
      double z = position.z();

      std::cout << "Read position: x: " << x
          << " y: " << y << " z: " << z << std::endl;
    }
  }
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main(int _argc, char **_argv)
{
  // Load gazebo
  gazebo::setupClient(_argc, _argv);

  // Create our node for communication
  gazebo::transport::NodePtr node(new gazebo::transport::Node());
  node->Init();

  // Listen to Gazebo pose info topic
  gazebo::transport::SubscriberPtr sub =
  node->Subscribe("~/pose/info", posesStampedCallback);

  // Busy wait loop...replace with your own code as needed.
  while (true)
    gazebo::common::Time::MSleep(10);

  // Make sure to shut everything down.
  gazebo::shutdown();
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8133/%E2%80%98setupclient%E2%80%99-is-not-a-member-of-%E2%80%98gazebo%E2%80%99?/) by [winston](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1084/winston/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 449 on 2015-03-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

your gazebo is probably too old, as you can see the tutorial applies for versions 4+

Cheers,
Andrei

---

Originally posted by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) with karma: 2108 on 2015-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [winston](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1084/winston/) on 2015-03-03**:
Yes, you are right. I just found out the answer but forgot to post it. 'setupClient' is not  defined in the old version of Gazebo. Thanks.

**Comment by [Lucas Walter](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/531/lucas-walter/) on 2017-07-06**:
In gazebo 7+ it is supposed to be `gazebo::client::setup(argc, argv)`, include gazebo_client.hh instead of gazebo.hh and need to include gazebo_config.hh initially to get GAZEBO_MAJOR_VERSION.